# Store positions of mouse clicks in a List<x, y> - Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, mouseevent

My problem is the following:
I have a Form and a 'pictureBox1' element in this Form.
I would like to get every mouse click position (in the 'pictureBox1' element) and store them in the List which would be declared globally.
I would be grateful for some sample codes.
Thanks.

Comment: Use the MouseDown event and add the points to a list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you need a list for that, but here's a simple coding to show the mouse position when clicked:

> ```
>     private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
>     {
>         Text = string.Format("[{0},{1}]",e.X,e.Y);
>     }
> ```
>
> Where 'Text' indicates the title of the form.

Anyway if you need to declare the position as a list, you can build up a class:

> ```
> class Position
> {
>     public int x { get; set; }
>     public int y { get; set; }
> }
> ```

Then in your form, call up a list globally:

> List< Position> MousePosition = new List< Position>();